# How to update the style of an element inside a repeat on mouseover

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to update the ng-style of an element in an ng-repeat on an ng-mouseover. I've tried a couple of ideas but can't seem to figure it out. Here's the basic idea behind my code:

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in days | orderBy:'timestamp'"
     ng-style="seriesStyle(data)"
     ng-mouseover="examineSeries(data)"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.examineSeries = function (data) {

    $scope.frame = data; // used for other things

    // want to update the width of the mouseover'd element's seriesStyle
    // here to something higher than 1%

}

$scope.seriesStyle = function (data) {

    return {
        'background-color': data.color,
        'width': '1%'
    }

}
```

**Please note I am unable to just put a class on every element and use :hover because of other dependencies.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the proper angular way to handle this thing is to create a directive that will examine the data on mouse over and update the style if required. 
take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uywoav34/2/) that shows how to do it

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="day in ctrl.days" ng-style="ctrl.seriesStyle(day)" update-on-mouse-over>{{day}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.controller('AppCtrl', function () {

  this.days = [
    {name:'Sun', color:'red'},
    {name:'Mon', color:'blue'},
    {name:'Tue', color:'orange'}
  ];

  this.seriesStyle = function (day) {
    return {
      'background-color': day.color
    };
  };

});

myapp.directive('updateOnMouseOver', function() {

return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('mouseover', function() {
            element.css('background-color', 'green');
        });
    }
  };
});
```